# Add checkbox to lock cells with dropdown lists in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

Suppose I have a Google Sheet where columns A:G are dropdown lists.

I would like to add an option to lock choices in columns A:G using a checkbox in column H, where checking the box in this column will lock columns A:G so they can not be edited (unless the checkbox in column H is de-selected).

Is it possible to do this on Google Sheets?

Comment: So basically you need a data validation in a way that each row from A to G will show specific options in the dropdown depending on the checkbox from H in the same row, am I right?

Comment: Are you also willing to use Apps Script to accomplish this?

Comment: @FernandoLara I would I would like to introduce a "lock options" column in column H. I would like A to G to be unlocked dropdown menus when the checkbox in H is not checked (ie these drop-down menus are active and the options in them can be selected and changed when the checkbox in H is not selected) . If the checkbox in column H is selected, then cells in columns A to G should not be allowed to change.

Comment: @FernandoLara yes I am willing to implement Apps Scripts if necessary.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. In your situation, who does check or uncheck the checkbox of column "H"? And, in your current situation, the column "H" has no checkboxes and you want to add the checkboxes using a script?

Comment: @Tanaike This is a sheet which can be accessed to anyone with a link. I would like to have the checkbox so that people don't accidentally change the selection on different rows

Comment: Thank you for replying. Now, I noticed that an answer has already been posted. In this case, I would like to respect the existing answer.

Comment: @NM_ If this answered your question, please click the accept button on the left (check icon). By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved. If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. [How to accept answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 0):

I have created the following script that is based on a previous script I found in a response here in StackOverflow a long time ago.

```
function onEdit(e) 
{
  var editRange = {
    top : 1,
    bottom : 1000,
    left : 2,
    right : 2
  };

  var cell = e.range;

  // Exit if we're out of range
  var thisRow = cell.getRow();
  if (thisRow < editRange.top || thisRow > editRange.bottom) return;

  var thisCol = cell.getColumn();
  if (thisCol < editRange.left || thisCol > editRange.right) return;

  var val1 = e.range.getRow();
  var val2 = e.range.getColumn();
  var validation = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Testing Sheet").getRange(val1, val2-1);


  if(cell.isChecked()){
    var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(['Red', 'Blue']).build();
  }
  else{
    var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(['Black', 'White']).build();
  }
  validation.setDataValidation(rule);
}
```

I modified the range at the beginning so it only recognizes the change in column B, but you can just change it to `8` for `column H`. Since the script uses an `onChange` trigger, what you need to validate first is if the edit was made in the range where the checkboxes are, then I set the range of the cell that I was going to change based on the value from the checkbox and created the data validation rule with the expected values depending on the conditional.

In your case you can just add the rest of the ranges for the other columns with more `validation` variables and change the column parameter to `-2`, `-3`, or `-4` depending on the cells you will be editing for example, and then create more validation rules according to the data you need in the dropdowns.

Here is an example of how this would work:

[image]

References:

- [onEdit()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite)
- [Data Validation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setdatavalidationrule)